# Iterative closest point (ICP) for Matlab with Covariance computation

Tags: matlab, covariance

does anybody know an implementation for the Iterative Closest Point (ICP) algorithm  in Matlab that computes the covariance matrix?

All i have found is the [icptoolboxformatlab](http://code.google.com/p/icptoolboxformatlab/) but it seems to be offline.

Answer (score 0):

http://censi.mit.edu/research/robot-perception/icpcov/

There is matlab code for 2D case. It provide ICP's covariance too.

I have implemented the 3D variant of Point to Point error metric based ICP covariance estimation, which is inspired from Andrea Censi's work.

Have a look at 
https://sites.google.com/site/icpcovariance/home